# Softkeyboard obscuring entire edittext except 1st line

Tags: android

Hi I have an edittext that when selected the keyboard pops up and the screen does scroll up to bring the edittext into view as it should, problem is only the 1st line is visible above the keyboard (the edittext is 6 lines high) - it only shits the display up enought to bring the first line into view

I can click in it and enter text and every new line scrolls the edittext up the screen

Is there any way for the ENTIRE edittext to be initally visible, ie scroll up until the bottom is visible.

Hope this makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
editText1.setSelection(editText1.getText().length());
```

It should make the cursor go immediately at the end of the text..

hence, the user will see all the text displayed in the edittext originally

Comment: Tried that 2nd line should read editText1.setSelection(editText1.getText().length());
No different, Should have said Im using an edit text to allow the user to input a few lines of text so it is initally set to "".

Comment: sorry.. updated the code.. however this is not the answer you are looking for right?.. what I think your asking is how to show the whole edittext box (with or without value)

Comment: Resolved by changing the edittext to a textview with the attributes 

android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:inputType="text"

Works properly now....but a bit of a bodge :/   thanks for your help. Yes I was looking to display the whole box with or without a value.

Comment: so the solution is actually an textview not an edittext.. good job :)

Comment: not quite !!! only allows single line of text (input type would prob have fixed it) but went back to editText and used the following xml declarations...NOW it works ! (only thing is text starts at bottom and scrolls up...but will do fine) android:gravity="bottom"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"